# An example of uncompleted measure space $(X,\mu,\mathcal M)$

Tags: measure-theory

We says that $(X,\mu,\mathcal M)$ is complete if whenever $F\in\mathcal M$ satisfy $\mu(F)=0$, and $E\subset F$, then $E\in\mathcal M$.

**1)** Does it mean that all set of measure $0$ are measurable ?

**2)** If there is such a definition, I think it mean that there is space that is uncompleted. Do you have such example ?

Answer (score 1):

A measure is defined **only** on measurable sets, so your first question doesn't really makes sense.

About the exemple, the most common space in integration, the Borel sigma algebra of $\Bbb R$ with the Lebesgue measure is not complete. The completion of this measure is the space of the Lebesgue sigma algebra

Comment: For 1) If I say: "*Does it mean that all set $E$ s.t. $\mu^*(E)=0$ is measurable ?*" would have more sense ?

Comment: @Rick : yes, that would makes far more sense, and would be correct

Answer (score 1):

It can be shown that $\mathbb{R}$ endowed with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra is not complete.

Comment: Just a quick remark : this is true only if you accept the axiom of choice ! Indeed, without axiom of choice, it's possible that all the Borel sets are measurable for the Lebesgue measure. Of course, analysis without axiom of choice is a little different !

Comment: @Tryss: All Borel set are anyway measurable. Do you talk about "all measurable are Borel" ? (with out axiom of choice)

Comment: @Rick : Sorry, I'm a little tired, and I start to doubt myself. What I meant is it's possible that, in some perfectly fine axiomatics without axiom of choice, **all** sets are measurable, but I don't remember if it's for the Lebesgue sigma algebra or for the Borel sigma algebra... :/

Comment: No problem, I will not consider this point :-)

Answer (score 1):

Let $\Omega$ be a set with at least two elements and $\mathcal{S} = \{\emptyset, \Omega\}$;  $(\Omega, \mathcal{S})$ is a measurable space.  Now let $\mu$ be the zero measure on $(\Omega, \mathcal{S})$.  The space
$(\Omega, \mathcal{S}, \mu)$ is not a complete measure space.  No proper nonvoid subset of $\Omega$ is measurable.

For any measure space $(\Omega, \mathcal{S}, \mu)$, you can enlarge $\mathcal{S}$ to $\overline{\mathcal{S}}$ by adding all subsets of sets of measure zero.  The measure $\mu$ can be extended to $\overline{\mathcal{S}}$; a little work is needed to show this works.